# Видеоконференция по локальной сети

Tags: видео

Подскажите какое-нибудь ПО для проведения видеоконференции, чтобы один мог видеть всех, а все одного или хотя бы слушатели могли просить слова или просто задавать вопрос, только локальная сеть без инета, можно с серверной частью, на ресурсы все равно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть свободная машинка, советую поставить в качестве сервачка и накатить туда [OpenMeetings](http://openkazan.info/http%3A/%252Fmy-ubuntu-land.blogspot.com/2011/03/openmeetings-161-debian-6-squeeze.html). Предварительно конечно по минимуму поставить Debian (или Ubuntu), apache2, MySQL+PhpMyAdmin. Вполне неплохая веб-мордочка для проведения видеоконференций и презентаций и устанавливается и настраивается за 10-15 минут (имею ввиду сам OpenMeetings).

Comment: настроил похожий сервер с программой "BBB" - большая синяя кнопка

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь - [Open Source Video Conferencing Server](http://code.google.com/p/openvcs/) - опенсорс однако.

Answer (score 1):

gstreamer

Запустить tcp-сервер для своего видео:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480 ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink port=5000
```

Подключиться к нему:

```
gst-launch-0.10 tcpclientsrc host=localhost port=5000 ! oggdemux ! theoradec ! autovideosink
```

С другим кодеком быстрее, но слабее сжатие:

- вместо ! theoraenc ! oggmux !
- пишем ! jpegenc ! multipartmux !

И соответственно для приёмника:

- вместо ! oggdemux ! theoradec !
- пишем ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec !

Вместо камеры транслируем часть своего рабочего стола (с теорой очень медленно, так что mjpeg):

```
gst-launch-0.10 ximagesrc starty=40 endx=1024 endy=840 ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=10/1 ! jpegenc ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink port=5000
```

Приём с автоматическим распознаванием формата потока. Можно забыть всё, что выше написано про приём и писать так:

```
gst-launch-0.10 tcpclientsrc host=localhost port=5000 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Настраивать видео в процессе трансляции можно с помощью gui-конфигурялки v4l2ucp. По трансляции звука аналогично, но пока не пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Connect](http://www.adobe.com/ru/products/adobeconnect.html) - проведение интерактивных конференций, есть поддержка видеосвязи.